# Return to appropriate Fragment from called Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So suppose there are 3 fragments, let's name them F1, F2 and F3. F3 can be called from both F1 and F2 by the following code:

```
        Fragment f3 = new F3();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("Id", String.valueOf(id));
        f3.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.f1_layout, f3).commit();
```

I wanna return to where I come from. What can be done? I've played with `addToBackStack` in different ways but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use `addToBackStack()` method :

```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(..............);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.f1_layout,f3).commit().addToBackStack(null);
```